# Replace strings in pandas cell using regex, between two specific strings

Tags: python, regex, pandas

there were some tipics connected with strings 'between' replacement, but I think I have something wrong in my regex, or maybe I should use different approach.

I need to replace in my `Name` column word (in this case `is` , but it will be not always `is`, sometime different word) with `is not`.
This specific world is between numbers ending with 'h'directly.

my df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Adam is 23.2h is 223h mike is 223h',
'Katie is 13.2h is 22h mike is 223h','Ilam is 2h is 223h mike is 223h',
'Katie','Brody','Brody like mike'],
'B':[20,20,21,21,22,21]})

    B                                Name
0  20  Adam is 23.2h is 223h mike is 223h
1  20  Katie is 13.2h is 22h mike is 223h
2  21     Ilam is 2h is 223h mike is 223h
3  21                               Katie
4  22                               Brody
5  21                     Brody like mike
```

expected output:

```
    B                                     Name
0  20   Adam is 23.2h is not 223h mike is 223h
1  20   Katie is 13.2h is not 22h mike is 223h
2  21      Ilam is 2h is not 223h mike is 223h
3  21                                    Katie
4  22                                    Brody
5  21                          Brody like mike
```

code:

```
df.Name=df.Name.replace({'([0-9]{1,8}.[0-9]{1,4}h|[0-9]{1,8}h)(.*?)([0-9]{1,8}.[0-9]{1,4}h|[0-9]{1,8}h)':'is not'},regex=True)
```

Comment: what is wrong with your code?

Comment: regex is replacing not only string between numbers with 'h' but those numbers as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use matching group write it `:r'\1 is not \3'` . And, seems, you can use a little easier regex

```
   df.Name.replace({'([0-9]{1,8}(?:.[0-9]{1,4})?h)(.*?)([0-9]{1,8}(.[0-9]{1,4})?h)':r'\1 is not \3'}, regex=True)

0    Adam is 23.2h is not 223h mike is 223h
1    Katie is 13.2h is not 22h mike is 223h
2       Ilam is 2h is not 223h mike is 223h
3                                     Katie
4                                     Brody
5                           Brody like mike
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: this is correct answer, could you explain this regex parts like `?:.`

Comment: It's a not capturing group. You can read some explanations there  - https://regex101.com/r/VX5xrM/1